# Include wildcards in sql server in the values themselves - not when searching with LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, wildcard

Is there a way to include wildcards in sql server in the values themselves - not when searching with LIKE?

I have a database that users search on. They search for model numbers that contain different wildcard characters but do not know that these wildcard characters exist.

For example, a model number may be 123*abc in the database, but the user will search for 1234abc because that's what they see for their model number on their unit at home.

I'm looking for a way to allow users to search without knowledge of wildcards but have a systematic way to include model numbers with wildcard characters in the database.

Comment: You might need to add a model synonyms table. In there you would insert one row for each value that 123*abc can have.

Comment: @jarlh almost - but the OP isn't using standard TSQL wildcards

Comment: What wildcards are you using and what are their meanings?

Comment: @MartinSmith, so stupid. Looks like I'm too much in VMS mode at the moment.

Comment: `'*'` isn't a wildcard in SQL Server though ,`'%'` (for multiple characters) and `'_'` (for single characters) are. You could replace the `*` with a `%` I suppose and use a `LIkE` expression; don't expect great performance though.

Comment: @MartinSmith * are used to represent any one character and parenthesis are used to represent specific characters- so in 123*abc, the * could be any one number or letter. However, if that model number was 123(4,5,a)abc then the model could be 1234abc, 1235abc, or 123aabc.

Comment: So you will be better off using SQL Server standard syntax for this `_` and `[45a]` then you can just use `WHERE @search_value LIKE column_name`

Comment: None of those expressions are valid for pattern matching in SQL Server, they would be treated as literal strings. If you can't change that then you would need to either have an application do the work for design a SQLCLR function to do the work. Plain T-SQL will not be friendly to do the work here.

Comment: Honestly, however, it sounds like the data is being stored poorly in your data engine. Rather than storing `'abc(1,2)456'` you should have 2 rows in your table `'abc1456'` and `'abc2456'`. Fix the data model, fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add a `PERSISTED` computed column to your table with valid pattern expression for SQL Server. You stated that `*` should be any letter or numerical character, and comma delimited values in parenthesis can be any one of those characters. Provided that commas don't appear in your main data, nor parenthesis, then this *should* work:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE SomeTable (SomeString varchar(15));
GO
INSERT INTO SomeTable
VALUES('123abc'),
      ('abc*987'),
      ('def(q,p,r,1)555');
GO
ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD SomeString_Exp AS REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SomeString,'*','[0-9A-z]'),'(','['),')',']'),',','') PERSISTED; --What you're interested in

SELECT *
FROM SomeTable;
GO

DECLARE @String varchar(15) = 'defp555';

SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE @String LIKE SomeString_Exp; --And how to search

GO

DROP TABLE SomeTable;
```

If `*` is any character, and noy any alphanumeric then you could shorten the whole thing to (and provided your on SQL Server 2017):

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD SomeString_Exp AS REPLACE(TRANSLATE(SomeString,'*()','_[]'),',','') PERSISTED;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking either:

```
where @model_number like replace(model_number, '*', '%')
```

or

```
where @model_number like replace(model_number, '*', '_')
```

Depending on whether `'*'` means any string (first example) or exactly one character (second example).